# this.media.setCurrentTime is not a function

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm having an issue-- firebug is showing the following error: "this.media.setCurrentTime is not a function"

It's coming from this line-

```
$(SB).on('load', function (e) {
    var player1 = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1');
    if(typeof SB.getBookmark() == "number" && SB.getBookmark() > 0){
        player1.setCurrentTime(SB.getBookmark());
    } else {
        player1.setCurrentTime('0');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer($('.js-call-video'), {

  success: function(mediaElement, domObject) {
    mediaElement.addEventListener("loadeddata", function(e) {
      return e.target.setCurrentTime("12");
    });

    return mediaElement.play();
  }
});
```